# How to specify multiple host in elasticsearch npm package?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I am using this npm package for elasticsearch -

"@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.15.0".

I try to specify multiple hosts in the node part but its not working -

````
const {
   Client
} = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({
    node: [ 'http://localhost:9200','http://localhost:9201']
})```

With a single IP it works fine, but its not taking an array of ip addresses. I even tried the now deprecated elasticsearch package but to no avail. Can somebody please help?
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/basic-config.html#basic-config), you need to specify the `nodes` setting instead of `node`, like this:

```
const {
   Client
} = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({
    nodes: [ 'http://localhost:9200','http://localhost:9201']
})      ^
        |
   add 's' here
```

Comment: With your help, I am able to specify ip in an array, but only a single one, as soon as I include the second elasticsearch address it starts giving issues. Thank you pointing this out though.

Comment: Glad it helps! Do you mind sharing what kind of "issues" you're having now?

Comment: Yea, its giving me 404 when I try to create an index, which means its not able to connect. Is there any condition that the nodes specified in the array should belong to the same cluster? Because the nodes I am supplying right now are two completely different elasticsearch instances running on two different ports, they don't know each other at all.

Comment: 404 is not a connection problem, it would be 5xx something. you cannot connect to two different clusters and hope that the client will know which one to contact based on the index names. You need two separate clients, one per cluster, otherwise, it's never gonna work